# Git pushing with wrong username when having multiple git accounts locally

Tags: git, ssh

I use three different GitHub accounts.

I have correctly set my ssh keys (created, added to keyring, added to github).

Doing `ssh-add -l` returns:

```
3072 SHA256:/Vq3tN5FxtE64LALAe25GQr+MpIPbGg mail@first.com (RSA)
3072 SHA256:9NheazRnzMzicLALA6z70kQeO6tQcNZcePJw0RRk mail@second.com (RSA)
3072 SHA256:r7uaTSfE9ZXn7LALAGHIn4syyaKPPyXsKdK8Sjk mail@third.com (RSA)
```

In my **~/.ssh/.config** file I have:

```
# GITHUB FIRST
Host github.com-first-user
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/first-user

# GITHUB SECOND
Host github.com-second-user
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/second-user
  
# GITHUB THIRD
Host github.com-third-user
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/third-user
```

In my global git config I did not add any user/email config.

Each repository contains the correct user and email.

When I try to push, it says that `first-user` doesn't have permission.

```
ERROR: Permission to user/repo.git denied to first-user.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I believe to have read somewhere that git uses the ssh key it sees, so maybe it is seeing the first key and taking that.

Doing `git config --list --show-origin --show-scope` in the repo folder, I get:

```
global  file:/home/user/.gitconfig    core.autocrlf=input
local   file:.git/config              user.name=Second
local   file:.git/config              user.email=mail@second.com
```

Nowhere is there any setup for the first user.

Doing `git remote -v` returns:

```
origin  git@github.com-second-user:user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com-second-user:user/repo.git (push)
```

**Relevant note:**

Doing `ssh -T github.com-second-user` returns *Hi **first-user**!, You've successfully authenticated...*

**Note**: this error happens both using the git cli, and also using git via the phpStorm UI.

How can I force it to use the second key for the second user?

Thanks!

Comment: The user+email in config are only used for the "author" and "committee" fields of commits. Credentials for the server appear in the url of your remote (`git remote -v`)

Comment: @LeGEC - Thanks, I didn't know that. In any case, I just updated the question with that info. It seems to be set up right too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

(either to each `Host` entry for the three aliases, or globally).  Without this setting, ssh *first* tries *all* the agent-supplied identities, *then* tries the file listed.  Since the first agent-supplied entity works as the first user, that gets you in to GitHub as the first user: the second user's key is never attempted, and GitHub believe you are the first user.

With `IdentitiesOnly yes`, ssh tries only the listed `IdentityFile` entries, in the order they appear (still getting keys from the agent as needed, so that you need only store the `.pub` files on the computer in question, if that's not your primary system).

(Nothing *Git* does here makes any difference: all of this is entirely up to ssh and GitHub.)

Comment: Working like a charm now. Thanks! Btw, I was confused about where to add it, looking this up, I added it at the end of the ssh config file, as:

Host * (new line)
IdentitiesOnly=yes

Comment: That works, or you can just list it before any `Host` block. I list it in each `Host` block myself, not for any reason of importance, but rather because if I didn't list a `Host` line, what identity should it use by default? (It's a sort of logic puzzle since the result would be the same either way.)

Answer (score 0):

To multiple github account on single machine: follow [this](https://gist.github.com/rahularity/86da20fe3858e6b311de068201d279e3#step-3)

Example of config file in ./ssh/config

```
Host user1
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privatekey-user1

Host user2
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privatekey-user2
```

user1 and user2 are username account github, example: like manhcntt21 in here.

[image]

each repository, you have to set name and email for each account github

```
    config --local user.name 
    config --local user.email
```